# Socket Module in Python Broken Pipe Error and Multi Clients

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

The aim is to have multiple clients connecting to the server,and send them packets of data while they are still connected. One-One communication works without any problems, and no broken pipe issues, the issue arises when we have multiple clients connecting to the server.

```
    import socket
    import os
    import time
    bind_ip      = '192.168.4.4'
    bind_port    =  12345
    payload      =  []
    devices      =  []
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_REUSEADDR,1)
    server.bind((bind_ip, bind_port))   
    server.listen(5)  # max backlog of connections
    print 'Listening on {}:{}'.format(bind_ip, bind_port)

    def send(counts, payload):
        x = counts     #No of iterations.
        y = 0

        start_time = time.time()
        while(x != 0):     
            try:
                client_socket, address = server.accept()
                devices.append(client_socket)
            except socket.error:
                break

            print client_socket
            print 'Accepted connection from {}:{}'.format(address[0], address[1])
            Post.IP.append(address[0])

            for z in devices:

                request = z.recv(1024)
                print 'Received: {}'.format(request)
                z.sendall(payload)

            x = x-1
            print "Count: " ,x+1
            print ""

        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        print ""
        print "Elapsed Time for " + str(10 * len(data)) + " packets is " + str(elapsed_time)
        print ""
        print "Connections"
        print Post.IP[0]
        client_socket.close()

send(2, bytearray(112, 100, 100, 100, 1))
```

So what I tried was to make a list of available clients, append them to the list and talk to each one of them separately. Once the counts crosses 3, the broken pipe error shows up.

I am doubting that the server closes the connection before it commences again, any help with this? Should I use threads to scan in the background?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to do a simple _TCP server_. Check this page: [\[SO\]: Sample server program (annotated)](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sockets/5668/python-tcp-sockets-simple-server-and-client-examples-with-annotation/20100/sample-server-program-annotated#t=201708311131210362471)

Comment: @CristiFati this handles only 1 client at a time. He was also talking about forking, any idea on that?

Comment: Everything in the outer `while` loop, after `accept`, should be placed in a separate function that should be executed either in a separate thread, or in a separate process (`os.fork()` or via _multiprocessing_ module). But anyway, you could _Google_ "Python tcp server" and browse the results, you'll definitely find smth useful.